# text selection is not working

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to achieve that, when i select some text on my page and then click on a button that i get this text via javascript.

```
function getSelText()
    {

        var t = '';
        if(window.getSelection){
            t = window.getSelection();
        }else if(document.getSelection){
            t = document.getSelection();
        }else if(document.selection){
            t = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        return t;
    }
```

i have got this function, but it is not working.

```
self.Copy = function () {
        alert(getSelText());
    }
```

The Copy function is working but the result of alert is always empty.

Comment: Clicking a button won't clear the selection, but clicking on anything else will clear the selection - basic behavior of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for me :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TestSelection () {
            if (window.getSelection) {  
                var selectionRange = window.getSelection ();                                        
                alert ("The text content of the selection:\n" + selectionRange.toString ());
            } 
            else {
                if (document.selection.type == 'None') {
                    alert ("No content is selected, or the selected content is not available!");
                }
                else {
                    var textRange = document.selection.createRange ();
                    alert ("The text content of the selection:\n" + textRange.text);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Select some text or <button>element</button>, or do not select anything, before you click on the button below.
    <br /><br />
    <button onclick="TestSelection ();">Test the selection!</button>
</body>
</html>
```